# How do Center Semantic UI Tab Menus React?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, tabs, center, semantic-ui-react

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#types-basic

I am trying to center the menu tabs to the center (left and right) but I can't figure it out the tab documentation. 
import React from 'react'
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react'

```
const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> },
]

const TabExampleBasic = () => <Tab panes={panes} />

export default TabExampleBasic
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
<Tab
      menu={{
        attached: true,
        tabular: true,
        style: {
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center"
        }
      }}
      panes={panes}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this :

> Tab menu={{ attached: true, tabular: 'right' }} panes={panes}

You can set tabular value to true, left or right.

You can find this on https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab also.

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't seem to work the way I just want to be center the tabs. I don't know if it is possible looking at the issues. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5589